# How to refresh file, convert and send email in one step?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, outlook

I am trying to:

- Access folder with about 250 Excel files (standardised but different customers in each)
- Refresh data in Excel (I feed the cube behind so I know when new information is loaded into the system)
- Save Excel file
- Convert Sheet1 to pdf and keep name of Excel file (e.g: Excel = MeCompany then pdf should be MeCompany.pdf)
- Transfer pdf to destinationfolder (not copy, but a real transfer)
- Rinse and repeat for all 250 reports
- Write one email via Outlook to several people and inform them that the reports are now all available

```vb
Sub Main()

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("ORIGINFOLDER_EXCEL”)
    Set arrFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each strFolderName In arrFiles
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFolderName)
    objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.refreshall
    for each objworksheet in Array(objworkbook.Worksheets("REPORT"))
        objWorksheet.Cells(2, 13) = "Jan-"
        objWorksheet.Cells(2, 14) = "Jun"
        objWorksheet.Cells(2, 15) = "2016"

    Next
    objExcel.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=" ORIGINFOLDER_EXCEL ", _
        ActiveSheet.Range("J1").Value & ".pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Next
    objFSO.MoveFile " ORIGINFOLDER_PDF " DESTINATIONFOLDER_PDF "

    Next
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
            .Subject = "Accountreporting data 062016"
            .To = "email1,email2,email3,…."
            .CC = " email1,email2,email3,….""
            .Body = "Dear recipient," & Chr(13) "data drive has been processed and finished. The reports are now available at:" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & DESTINATIONFOLDER_PDF" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Kind regards," & Chr(13) & "BST" & Chr(13) & "Departmentname" 
            .Send
    End With
        MsgBox "Automatic delivery successfully finished", 64
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Mail_Object = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: you have 2 `For` and 3 `Next` ? that's 1 "Bouns" , you need to find the missing `For` or remove one of the `Next`

Comment: The 250 excel-files are still not completed as this whole project is still in progress. I am just afraid to end up in a loop (endless) or to send an email of notification for each report.....

Comment: @ShaiRado: thank you! I did not even see that! As I said I am a starter in this language and things like that are slipping all the time :)

Comment: I've just re-written this code. There is no way it currently works. It has a number syntax errors, ideally you should have approached SO with the errors you are facing not just the result you want.

Comment: @GaryEvans I would really like to do that but at the moment I do not have enough of the "new" excel-files this script shall refresh and publish to really try it out.  Would you reccomend to just work with some (about 50) dummies and send the error messages afterwards?

Comment: Yes, A dummy file takes seconds and it means you can prep your work before the live work comes in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have re-written this procedure (untested) to help you understand VBA a little more as there are a number of issues, the result is still similar to your code but slightly clearer. There are a lot of ways to do the same thing, I could have written it as my own but I specifically want to retain as much of your code as possible to make it possible to relate to the issues better.

---

Starting with the issues I encountered:-

`Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("ORIGINFOLDER_EXCEL”)` - Was `ORIGINFOLDER_EXCEL` a variable before you posted? Currently it is a string. A variable is a container that holds the value. If it was a variable `ORIGINFOLDER_EXCEL` could in fact equal `C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\Here\`, and that would make it a valid path, but as a string you are asking it use `ORIGINFOLDER_EXCEL` as the exact folder path, this will throw an error of folder not found. Also, the closing quote is a curly bracket, this is not a valid encapsulating character, use a standard double quote (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> on my British-UK keyboard). So `"` is valid, `”` is not, subtle but important.

`Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` - If you are in Excel you do not need to do this, you can use `Application` to use the existing open instance of Excel.

`for each objworksheet in Array(objworkbook.Worksheets("REPORT"))` - I've not seen this done before but it looks like you are just trying to connect to one worksheet in the workbook, a loop (`For Each`) is not needed here, in [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_programming) terms you can simply say 'Make the object `objworksheet` a reference to the worksheet `REPORT` in the workbook `objworkbook`.

`objFSO.MoveFile " ORIGINFOLDER_PDF " DESTINATIONFOLDER_PDF "` - The use of double quotes makes this line invalid, the [VBE](http://www.homeandlearn.org/the_excel_vba_editor.html) would have shown it up as an issue and the code could not run. When creating the PDF, it would be better to save it directly where it needs to go.

`With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)` - For a mail item (email) you will need a zero (`0`) not o (`o`).

`.To = "email1,email2,email3,…."` - An ellipsis is not valid here but I appreciate this is probably being updated later.

`.CC = " email1,email2,email3,….""` - Syntax is important, you have an extra space after the opening double quote and then two double quotes at the end of the string making for an invalid line of code.

`.Body = "Dear recipient," & Chr(13) "data drive has been processed and finished. The reports are now available at:" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & DESTINATIONFOLDER_PDF" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Kind regards," & Chr(13) & "BST" & Chr(13) & "Departmentname"` - This is a syntax issue, missing `&` after the first `Chr(13)` and then a lone double quote after `DESTINATIONFOLDER_PDF`.

---

They were the core issues I saw, some tips that may help you in the future.

When learning VBA, don't late bind unless you have to. Presumably you got your code from the internet in which someone had used late binding but when learning, its not worth it unless required. There are two types of binding, late and early. Binding refers to connecting to a toolset, a toolset is what can do a specific tasks for you. For example your `objFSO` creates a reference to the toolset that enables file system manipulation and navigation. The way you have done it is called late binding, that means the code binds to the toolset after it has started running. Early binding is telling your project you need that toolset at the start so it knows about it before the code starts running. The benefit of this is intellisense, a powerful ally in learning VBA and what a toolset does. Intellisense is putting a fullstop at the end of something and a list of next options appearing pops up, or opening a bracket for a function and seeing what can be passed into it.

To early bind you would go `Tools` > `References...` and tick `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`, then in your code you can change `Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` to `Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject` to get to know this toolset better.

My other tip would be indent, it makes code readable and easier to follow, with indentation it would be clearer for you and us to see things like the next/for loop mismatch.

---

On to the rewrite, I have:-

- Placed comments in the code to help explain whats happening
- Left it late bound for you to relate and understand (and try changing yourself)
- Fully indented
- Closed all of the references I open as good practice.

Hope this helps, as I mentioned it is untested at to be used as a starting point to get where you need to be, your initial code was broken without information on where you were experiencing issues, this should address some of those issue even though they were not mentioned.

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim objFSO          As Object
Dim objFolder       As Object
Dim objFile         As Object
Dim ObjOl           As Object
Dim StrSrcFolder    As String
Dim StrDestFolder   As String
Dim StrFolderName   As String
Dim WkBk            As Workbook
Dim WkSht           As Worksheet

'set source and destination folders
StrSrcFolder = "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\Source\"
StrDestFolder = "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\Destination\"

'Connect to FSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Open the source folder
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(StrSrcFolder)
        'Loop through each file in the folder
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            'Only procees xls and xlsx files
            If (UCase(Right(objFile.Name, 4)) = ".xls") Or (UCase(Right(objFile.Name, 5)) = ".xlsx") Then
                'Open the workbook
                Set WkBk = Application.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
                    WkBk.RefreshAll
                    Set WkSht = WkBk.Worksheets("REPORT")
                        WkSht.Cells(2, 13) = "Jan-"
                        WkSht.Cells(2, 14) = "Jun"
                        WkSht.Cells(2, 15) = "2016"
                        'Export it as a PDF straight to the destination
                        WkSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                                    Filename:=StrDestFolder & WkSht.Range("J1") & ".pdf", _
                                                    OpenAfterPublish:=False
                    Set WkSht = Nothing
                    'Save and close the workbook
                    WkBk.Close 1
                Set WkBk = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

'Connect to Outlook
Set ObjOl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Create and send an email
    With ObjOl.CreateItem(0)
        .Subject = "Account reporting data 062016"
        .To = "email1,email2,email3"
        .CC = "email4,email5,email6"
        .Body = "Dear recipient," & Chr(13) & "Data drive has been processed and finished. The reports are now available at:" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & StrDestFolder & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Kind regards," & Chr(13) & "BST" & Chr(13) & "Departmentname"
        .Send
    End With
Set ObjOl = Nothing

MsgBox "Automatic delivery successfully finished", 64

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gary!Thank you for the help! Sorry that I could not come back to you sooner - I had a meeting abroad and therefore no chance to log in. VBA is looking way easier when a professional is doing it. The filenames you mentioned (eg "ORIGINFOLDER_EXCEL") are just a short desription as the whole path is endless. In my try I of course used the whole "\\gate01\T\User\File...... Same for the others.   Your script is helping me big times! It will take some time (in my case about a week I suppose :) ) to understand but this look so sophisticated. THANK YOU A LOT!

Comment: I finished 5 dummy files and will try to run the script. Let's see what the system has to say about it.
Furthermore: Thank you for the tip wit " vs ''.....I did not even see that there is a difference. Might really be an issue!

Comment: Okay, here is what happened (quite funny actually). The script started without a hitch and after about 2 seconds I got the email with the message that the Email was sent. 
The strange thing is, that there were no .pdf in the destinationfolder. I checked the path twice and tried different styles ('S:\' and '\\teamgate\').

No error message popped up for me.

BUT THANK YOU AGAIN! Has anybody ever told you, that you are a genius? :) Your script helped me understand the whole process better. Hopefully I get better at vba soon.

Comment: Thank you :-D. The issue must be in the `WkSht.ExportAsFixedFormat` line. stop it in debug and check `StrDestFolder` is a valid path (copy and paste its value into windows explorer address bar), and check that `WkSht.Range("J1") & ".pdf"` will create a valid file name.

Comment: I. HATE. THIS. SYSTEM.....as it seems one of the pivots I inserted in ALL THE FILES (!!!) shows a slightly different path than the others (S:\ and NOT \\teamgate\S\.....so this little "§$=%)") always blocked every refresh from the start. The path IS correct but somehow it does only work with the long UNC Path.... excel even asks me if I want to change the path (but for every report seperately of course)...I will have to change that but otherwise it seems to work now. Thanks again! I am finally freeeeee :D